# Linked List sorting

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I want to be able to sort via another method (`getPrice`), my code is:

```
void gameListType::sortAscending() {
    nodeType<gameType> *current;
    nodeType<gameType> *next;
    nodeType<gameType> *tempcurrent;
    nodeType<gameType> *tempnext;
    nodeType<gameType> *tempprev;
    nodeType<gameType> *prev;
    prev = first;
    current = first->link;
    next = current->link;
    while ( current->link !=NULL){
        if (current->info.getPrice() > next->info.getPrice())
        {
            tempcurrent =current;
            tempprev = prev;
            tempnext = next;
            tempcurrent ->link = tempnext->link;
            tempnext ->link= tempprev->link;
        }
        prev = prev ->link;
        current = current ->link;
        next = next->link;
    }
}
```

How can I change my code so that I can sort the nodes according to the getPrice() method?

Comment: maybe your tags are wrong? @edit better ;)

Comment: Have you considered using `std::list<>` - it has a `sort` member function that accepts a comparison object letting you customise the sort critiera... see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort)

Answer (score 0):

Use a predicate for sorting.

```
void gameListType::sort(std::function<bool(gameType, gameType)> predicate)
{
    nodeType<gameType> *current;
    nodeType<gameType> *next;
    nodeType<gameType> *tempcurrent;
    nodeType<gameType> *tempnext;
    nodeType<gameType> *tempprev;
    nodeType<gameType> *prev;
    prev = first;
    current = first->link;
    next = current->link;
    while ( current->link !=NULL) {
        if (predicate(current->info, next->info))
        {
            tempcurrent =current;
            tempprev = prev;
            tempnext = next;
            tempcurrent ->link = tempnext->link;
            tempnext ->link= tempprev->link;
        }
        prev = prev ->link;
        current = current ->link;
        next = next->link;
    }
}

// sort ascending
sort([](gameType const& t1, gameType const& t2) {return t1.getPrice() > t2.getPrice();});

// sort desscending
sort([](gameType const& t1, gameType const& t2) {return t1.getPrice() < t2.getPrice();});
```